# BlackBerry webworks native dialog unicode

Tags: blackberry, unicode, dialog, alert, blackberry-webworks

I have been searching for an answer all around the web, but couldn't find anything.
I am developing Blackberry Webworks application and the problem is with dialog and unicode. For example:

when I use simple javascript alert(unicodeMsg); unicode works fine, I can use any character including Russian or Lithuanian. The problem is that the alert box has title "JavaScript Alert" and it annoys a bit.

when I use native alert either phonegap or webworks like:

> blackberry.ui.dialog.standardAskAsync(unicodeMsg,
>   blackberry.ui.dialog.D_OK, {
>   title : unicodeTitle, 
>   size: blackberry.ui.dialog.SIZE_MEDIUM, 
>   position : blackberry.ui.dialog.CENTER
>   });

it doesn't show any unicode characters. I tried pretty much everything (setting my document in utf-8, using \uxxxx characters, changing meta tags from utf-8 to windows-1257 but nothing works)

I suppose the problem is not with html or js documents neither with the script. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the alert, with the incorrect or missing characters?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the unicode characters like so `text: unescape(encodeURIComponent(unicodeStr))` .

There is an example here - http://blackberry-webworks.github.com/WebWorks-API-Docs/WebWorks-API-Docs-next-BB10/view/blackberry.invoke.html